# View above the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a view above the status bar in ios9:

```
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    statusWindow.hidden = NO;
    statusWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.7];
    [statusWindow setRootViewController:self];
    [statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I only get a black screen with the status bar not covered. Any idea why it's not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this : https://github.com/kevingibbon/KGStatusBar
It works pretty well. It's the only framework I found which is working with iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go ahead and assume you are writing your code based off of this thread:

[Add UIView Above All Other Views, Including StatusBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666792/add-uiview-above-all-other-views-including-statusbar)

That being said, why are you setting:

```
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
```

It should be:

```
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
```

In the future, please add references to any threads you have looked at as well.

Good luck!